# maven project required sun.javadoc jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i came across this http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javadoc/javadoc  but it stated sun not allow redistribution.  i have a maven project that required to use com.sun.javadoc.*  . which repository can i use to grab the dependency?

p/s: i'm using eclipse

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking but classes from `com.sun.javadoc` are in `tools.jar` (which can't be distributed). If for whatever reason you need these classes on the class path, add the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

See [How do I include tools.jar in my dependencies?‎](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the regular maven-javadoc-plugin which runs the javadoc from your JDK, which you already have a valid copy of. Be sure that JAVA_HOME points to a JDK and not a JRE, and that the 'java' command in your path is from the JDK, not the JRE.

Comment: i added dependency like above in pom.xml but com.sun.* still not found and give error . my full pom.xml look like http://tinyurl.com/ya83kgj

Comment: Check that your JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH are correct and that the javadoc jar is present in the correct location.

Comment: yup my java_home path is correct. com.sun.javadoc in inside this file D:\work\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\src.zip

Comment: the src.zip is not relevant. It's never in classpath.